# python: count and replace pattern in string without regex

Tags: python, string, replace

What is the non-regex equivalent of `subn`? I would like to replace a pattern in a string and count how many times was the pattern replaced.
I ended up with:

```
def replacen(pat, repl, txt):
    txt2 = txt.replace(pat, repl)
    if (len(pat) != len(repl)):
        return (txt2, (len(txt) - len(txt2)) / (len(pat) - len(repl)))
    else:
        return (txt2, txt.count(pat))
```

Is there a more elegant solution?

Comment: This would be a more appropriate question for http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Answer (score 3):

Your own code can simply return txt2 and the count of the pattern:

```
def replacen(pat, repl, txt):
    txt2 = txt.replace(pat, repl)
    return txt2, txt.count(pat)
```

If nothing gets replaced then it is because you found no matching substring so count will return `0` if you replaced 5 `substring/pats` then txt.count(pat) is going to give you 5

Comment: Its very funny rally some times we missed the answers in our life because of those simplicity :-D

Comment: right, but I don't want to use `count` unless I have to (for efficiency considerations)

Comment: I doubt you'll get more efficient than `count`.

Comment: `count` is at least O(n) while checking the lengths is O(1)